# Apply graphics filter to QIcon in Qt5

Tags: image-processing, graphics, icons, qt5

I am trying to do something that to my surprise was much harder than first anticipated. I have a small bitmap resource that is 32bit png that I would like to display as an icon after tinting it to a specific color.

I came across [QGraphicsEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html) class and its children but it wont work unless I set up a whole scene graph which is kind of overkill for my purpose (rendering a 16x16 icon in different colors).

I also came across [QPixmapFilter](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/db/d83/class_q_pixmap_filter.html#details) class in **Qt4** but I can't find any reference for it in **Qt5**. Was it removed?

Also there is clearly some filters working on icons as seen in the [widget icons example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-icons-example.html) with both tints and blurs going on.

So how can I accomplish this simple task in Qt5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a better answer arrives I decided to share the approach I ended up using. It's not IMO a very elegant solution, but it works. It preserves transparency and I have tested it to work on SVG resources as well.

**Tint icon function for Qt5:**

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsEffect>

QImage tint(QImage src, QColor color, qreal strength=1.0){
    if(src.isNull()) return QImage();
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item;
    item.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(src));
    QGraphicsColorizeEffect effect;
    effect.setColor(color);
    effect.setStrength(strength);
    item.setGraphicsEffect(&effect);
    scene.addItem(&item);
    QImage res(src);
    QPainter ptr(&res);
    scene.render(&ptr, QRectF(), src.rect() );
    return res;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
QIcon ic(QPixmap::fromImage(tint(QImage("://icons/spider.svg"),QColor(192,0,0),1.0)));
```

This produces a readily tinted `QIcon` instance from arbitrary graphics resource.